# How to ignore certain letters and spaces in character arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Trying to make an else statement that get rid of all other letter and spaces then the ones i want.  This function is to change user inputted letters into other letters

```
using namespace std;
    void dna_to_rna(char rna[]) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (rna[i] == 'a' || rna[i] == 'A')
                rna[i] = 'U';
            else if (rna[i] == 'c' || rna[i] == 'C')
                rna[i] = 'G';
            else if (rna[i] == 'g' || rna[i] == 'G')
                rna[i] = 'C';
            else if (rna[i] == 't' || rna[i] == 'T')
                rna[i] = 'A';
}
```

What should the else statement look like in order to drop all other chars?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: The question is poorly worded. My assumption is that you want to ignore letters that are not acgt. Is that correct?

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough it's 4 o'clock in the morning and I'm a little tired

Comment: Your code looks more or less correct. What is the problem ?

Comment: @VbaGGz could you edit your question and make clear what _excactly_ you want?

Comment: • As in the input become Us in the output.
• Cs in the input become Gs in the output.
• Gs in the input become Cs in the output.
• Ts in the input become As in the output.
• any other input characters should disappear from the output altogether

Comment: @VbaGGz don't post that in a comment, but update your question.

Comment: what should the else statement look like in order to drop all other chars.

Comment: Is using a std::vector instead of an array an option?

Comment: @VbaGGz easiest way for me is copying the whole string transforming and eliminating unwanted characters into a temporary buffer and then copy the buffer back to `rna`. Your existing code is a perfect start for this. BTW you are taking a C approach and not at all a C++ approach.

Comment: @MichaelWalz i'm a beginner at this, is there anything more you can do to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a second array and as long as the information that I was looking for met the criteria that was necessary I placed it into the second array making sure that the position that I was placing it in the array was always in the right spot by creating a second variable that would count the the proper position in the array then just `cout` array

```
using namespace std;
    void dna_to_rna(char rna[])
    {
        int x = 0;
        char newrna[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (rna[i] == 'a' || rna[i] == 'A')
            {
                newrna[x] = 'U';
                x++;
            }
            else if (rna[i] == 'c' || rna[i] == 'C')
            {
                newrna[x] = 'G';
                x++;
            }
            else if (rna[i] == 'g' || rna[i] == 'G')
            {
                newrna[x] = 'C';
                x++;
            }
            else if (rna[i] == 't' || rna[i] == 'T')
            {
                newrna[x] = 'A';
                x++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
using namespace std;
void dna_to_rna(char rna[]) 
{
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (rna[i] == 'a' || rna[i] == 'A')
            s += 'U';
        else if (rna[i] == 'c' || rna[i] == 'C')
            s += 'G';
        else if (rna[i] == 'g' || rna[i] == 'G')
            s += 'C';
        else if (rna[i] == 't' || rna[i] == 'T')
            s += 'A';
     }
     strcpy(rna, s.c_str());
}
```

The idea is simply to use a std::string as a temporary buffer. The string is empty to start with. Then you add the characters you want one-by-one. When done with the loop, copy the content of the std::string back to the rna-array.

Answer (score 1):

If the input parameter can be changed to `std::string`, then you can use one of the following implementation:

```
void dna_to_rna(std::string& rna)
{
    auto it = rna.begin();
    while (it != rna.end())
    {
        if      (*it == 'a' || *it == 'A') *it = 'U';
        else if (*it == 'c' || *it == 'C') *it = 'G';
        else if (*it == 'g' || *it == 'G') *it = 'C';
        else if (*it == 't' || *it == 'T') *it = 'A';
        else
        {
            it = rna.erase(it);
            continue;   // it already "points" to the next element
        }

        ++it;
    }
}

std::string dna_to_rna(const std::string& dna)
{
    std::string rna;
    for (auto c : dna)
    {
        if      (c == 'a' || c == 'A') rna += 'U';
        else if (c == 'c' || c == 'C') rna += 'G';
        else if (c == 'g' || c == 'G') rna += 'C';
        else if (c == 't' || c == 'T') rna += 'A';
    }

    return rna;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make you code much simpler, and easier to read:

```
using namespace std;

void dna_to_rna(char rna[]) {

    int arrLength = sizeof(rna)/sizeof(rna[0]);  // Get size of array

    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        if (toupper(rna[i]) == 'A'){
            rna[i] = 'U';
        }
        else if (toupper(rna[i]) == 'C') {
            rna[i] = 'G';
        }
        else if (toupper(rna[i]) == 'G'){
            rna[i] = 'C';
        }
        else if (toupper(rna[i]) == 'T'){
            rna[i] = 'A';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't get the size of the array that way. `sizeof` on array function parameter `rna` will return size of `char *` not of the array, it should be done before calling the function.